# Concatenate rows based on group by a column value

Tags: r

I have a data which i need to group on column ID and then concatenate the rows in R studio.

Could anyone please help?

**Current Data**

```
ID   Name   Diagnosis    Medicine
1    A      a            a
1    A      b            a
1    A      c            b 
2    B      d            b
2    B      e            c
3    C      f            d
```

**Result Expected**

```
ID   Name   Diagnosis    Medicine
1    A      a|b|c         a|a|b
2    B      d|e           b|c
3    C      f             d
```

Code written till now is
diagnoses<-read_xlsx("excel file.xlsx")

diagnoses <-diagnoses[,c(     "ID"
,"Name"
,"Diagnosis"
,"Medicine"),]
head(diagnoses)

aggregate(cbind(Diagnosis, Medicine)~ID, df, paste0, collapse = '|')
write.xlsx(diagnoses, "Diagnoses.xlsx")

I am getting error :( Please help

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(Diagnosis, Medicine)~ID, df, paste0, collapse = '|')`

Comment: diagnoses<-read_xlsx("excel file.xlsx")
diagnoses <-diagnoses[,c(     "ID"
                              ,"Name"
                              ,"Diagnosis"
                              ,"Medicine"
),]
head(diagnoses)

aggregate(cbind(Diagnosis, Medicine)~ID, df, paste0, collapse = '|') 
     write.xlsx(diagnoses, "Diagnoses.xlsx")
I am still getting error :( Please help